# df.replace regex from hex to binary

Tags: python, pandas, binary, hex

I am trying to convert hex to binary in a pandas column. Object types.

I have converted F to 1111 no problem, now how can i go from 0-F ??

```
df1 = df["SFROW_ID"].replace(to_replace=r'F', value='1111', regex=True)
```

OUTPUT so far

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to `int` and then back to binary:

```py
df["SFROW_ID"].map(lambda x: f"{int(x, 16):012b}")
```

```sh
df
   A SFROW_ID
0  1      247
1  2       FC
2  3      2D0
3  4      001
4  5      068

df1
   A      SFROW_ID
0  1  001001000111
1  2  000011111100
2  3  001011010000
3  4  000000000001
4  5  000001101000
```

Comment: I will have a look at that , is there a FLAG to make sure the output is 12 bits from the HEX values in col "SFROW_ID" , I would need the leading zeros, thanks